# Calcular al inverso

Tags: javascript

Saludos amigos. Tengo un duda de cómo debería implementar esta función. Actualmente ella me hace el cálculo de porcentaje bien, pero ahora quisiera ponerle para que me calcule al inverso.

**Formulario**

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="input-field col s12 m6">
        <input id="icon_prefix" class="black-text" type="text" name="cod_ticket" autocomplete="off" title="Disculpa, el n° de recibo debe contener nimino 5 digitos" pattern="[0-9]{4,10}" required/>
        <label for="cedula" class="black-text ">Cód Ticket:</label>
    </div>

    <div class="input-field col s12 m6">
        <select name="id_puntos" class="browser-default"  required/>
            <option value="" disabled selected>Punto:</option>
            <?php
                $consulta = $DB_con->query("SELECT * FROM puntos ORDER BY id_puntos");
                while ($linea = $consulta->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) { ?>
                    <option value="<?php echo $linea['id_puntos'] ;?>">
                        <?php echo $linea['puntos'] ;?>
                    </option>
            <?php
                }
            ?>
        </select>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="row">
    <div class="input-field col s12 m3">
        <input id="icon_prefix"  type="text" class="black-text" name="monto" autocomplete="off" title="Disculpa, seleccione una fecha" pattern="[0-9]{4,8}" required/>
        <label for="monto" class="black-text ">Monto Transferencia:</label>
    </div>

    <div class="input-field col s12 m3">
        <select name="porcentaje" class="browser-default" onblur="calcula_porcentajes(this.form)" required/>
            <option value="" disabled selected>Porcentaje:</option>
            <?php
                $consulta = $DB_con->query("SELECT * FROM porcentaje ORDER BY id_porcentaje");
                while ($linea = $consulta->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) { ?>
                    <option value="<?php echo $linea['porcentaje'] ;?>">
                        <?php echo $linea['porcentaje']; ?>%
                    </option>
            <?php
                }
            ?>
        </select>
    </div>

    <div class="input-field col s12 m3">
        <input id="icon_prefix"  type="text" class="black-text" name="ganancia"  readonly/>
        <label for="cedula" class="black-text ">Ganancia:</label>
    </div>

    <div class="input-field col s12 m3">
        <input id="icon_prefix"  type="text" class="black-text" name="total" autocomplete="off" required/>
        <label for="cedula" class="black-text ">Total:</label>
    </div>
</div>
```

**función normal**

```
<script language="javascript">
    function calcula_porcentajes (form) {
        var resultado;
        var resultado2;
        var x = 0;
        var y = 0;
        x = parseInt (form.monto.value);
        y = parseInt (form.porcentaje.value);

        resultado = x * y / 100;
        form.ganancia.value = resultado;

        resultado2 = x + resultado;
        form.total.value = resultado2;

    }
</script>
```

**función inverso**

```
 <script language="javascript">
     function calcula_porcentajes_inverso(form){
       var resultado;
       var resultado2;
       var x=0;
       var y=0;
       x = parseInt (form.total.value);
       y = parseInt (form.porcentaje.value);


       resultado = x * y/100;
       form.ganancia.value=resultado;


       resultado2 = x - resultado;
       form.monto.value=resultado2;


    }
 </script>
```

Comment: ¿Por qué no llamas mejor a una función que a la vez llame a tus dos funciones? Creo que sería lo más práctico.

Comment: y como tendría que hacerlo para que me llame las dos al mismo tiempo

Comment: Te pongo el ejemplo en una respuesta.

Comment: Mezclar el código `HTML` y `PHP`, aparte de ser ilegible te dará a la larga muchos dolores de cabeza. Intenta hacer pequeños templates con tu código `HTML` y sepáralo del código `PHP`. [Aquí](https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2011/10/getting-started-with-php-templating/) te dejo más info.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Después de hablar por el chat ahora comprendo lo que deseas hacer. Lo que desas es que tu función calcule de diferente forma dependiendo de los elementos que se hayan rellenado. Si solo se ha llenado el campo `monto` debe hacer un cálculo y si solo se ha llenado el `total` debe hacer otro.

Esto lo puedes hacer chequeando dentro de tu función qué campos están llenos y qué campos no. Observa el siguiente snippet:

```js
document.querySelector("form input[name='porcentaje']").addEventListener("blur", calcula);

function calcula(evt) {

  var form = evt.currentTarget.form;
  var monto = form.monto.value;
  var porcentaje = form.porcentaje.value;
  var total = form.total.value;
  var resultado = 0;

  if (porcentaje.length === 0) { return; }
  if (monto.length === 0 && total.length === 0) { return; }
  porcentaje = parseInt(porcentaje);

  if (total.length === 0) {

    monto = parseInt(monto);
    resultado = monto * porcentaje / 100;
    form.total.value = Math.round(monto + resultado);

  } else {

    total = parseInt(total);
    resultado = (total * porcentaje) / 100;
    form.monto.value = Math.round(total - resultado);

  }

  form.ganancia.value = Math.round(resultado);

}
```

```html
<form>
  <input type="text" name="monto" placeholder="monto" />
  <input type="text" name="porcentaje" placeholder="porcentaje" />
  <input type="text" name="ganancia" placeholder="ganancia" />
  <input type="text" name="total" placeholder="total" />
</form>
```

Comment: me da error y me hace el calculo malo

Comment: ¿Qué error te da? El cálculo es el mismo que situaste en tu pregunta, no lo he variado.

Comment: hace el calculo mal y si le doy al inverso se cae todo

Comment: Repito, el cálculo es el mismo que situaste en tu pregunta. Y en el cual te hago la observación de que en la segunda función estás usando los valores para calcular que anteriormente variaste en la primera función. Lo único que he realizado es que puedas llamar a las dos funciones como querías. Dime cuál es el error que te da.

Comment: puedes trasladar el debate a una sala de chat para explicarte bien para no hacer las preguntas tan largas

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/62323/discussion-between-elchininet-and-yoclens).